# Django can't find images and static files

Tags: django, server, django-templates

I use django and my site works perfect but cant load images. I guess wrong thing is paths but i can't fix it. I see questions like that and apply all of them to my site but they did not work, please someone help me, i can't solve that for a few days.

[image]

[image]

NOTE : my site works fine on localhost, on my computer but don't work on server

Comment: are you using SQLite?

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: In localhost you can do this but if you are making it to work on server then you should use `PostgreSql` or `MySql` because on local host files are stored locally and you can access them with the local path but if you are working on server then you must store those files on cloud or persistence storage.

Comment: The [static files docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#depl‌​oyment) explain how to configure static files in production. You haven't shown a single line of your Django or server configuration, so we can't possibly help.

Answer (score 6):

Create a folder called `static` in your project directory or your app directory. Create another folder inside `static` called `images`.

In your `settings.py` file, add this line.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In your template file add this to the first line.

```
{% load static %}
```

In your template, use code like this to get the image to show.

```
<img src="{% static "image/example.jpg" %}"/>
```

Add the following lines in `settings.py`.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Finally go to your server project folder and use the following command.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This command will copy all static files (e.g. images) from you static folders and paste it in folder you mentioned in `STATIC_ROOT`, in this case the folder is `staticfiles`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fix STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), ] to avoid error (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting. Django version: 2.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still of interest, but have been having the same problem and I had to do some searching. Here is the solution (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/ )

My understanding is that STATIC_ROOT acts as a "management repository" after you run collectstatic, and Django doesn't serve the files from there. You need to set up a separate folder. This is because in production, as flagged above, the suggestion is to have a separate server dedicated to such files.

In my case, I just created a separate folder next to static,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),)
```

Note, that this is NOT THE RECOMMENDED PLACE to PUT IT, and the above STATICFILES_DIRS should be separate, OUTSIDE your project folder/on a separate server. I put it there as my project was small, for testing purposes.

As flagged in the official documents too, you need to run collectstatic everytime a file there changes, and AFTER THAT you need to COPY THE FILES to the directory from where they are actually served, ie the directory that DJANGO is actually reading.

No changes are needed to the template(s).

Small add-on: the above is necessary (at least I found it so) for media/image files. Does not apply to the css/js files, which work just fine out of the normal '/static/' folder. Wanted to add this as I found LOTS of guides/explanations about setting up this '/static/' folder and collect static, but almost none about taking the additional step of moving images to a separate folder, STATICFILES_DIRS (or whatever name you want to set).

Answer (score 0):

it is not about path, i guess. Becuse here is another basic project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1aM7.png)

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1><img src='static/ben2.jpg'></h1>")
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'key

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_server_ip']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-
validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':
```

'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'
,
        },
        {
            'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]

```
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have tried all combinations like what you said :D but they did not help me

Answer (score -1):

Below STATIC_URL line,  insert this :

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.join.path(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer and format your answer, it can do wonders!!